# Nmap does not show all open ports

Tags: networking, port, nmap

When I run `nmap -p- 10.129.175.12` I get

```
Host is up (0.00026s latency).
Not shown: 65534 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

But I know that there is a `5985` port that is open too. If I use `nmap -p 5985 10.129.175.12` I can see that this port is actually open.

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-10 17:31 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.129.175.12
Host is up (0.0065s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5985/tcp open  wsman
```

So why Nmap does not see that this port is open when scanning with `-p-`?

P.S. I'm running it with root.

Comment: Can this machine be reached by the public internet so I can help debug? what is the output with the ```-vv``` flag?

Comment: Try this `nmap -p5900-6000 10.129.175.12` , where the "Port of Interest" is included. That may help Debug the Issue. Check with `--max-retries` to avoid Intermittent Issues. Check `--scan-delay` to avoid overload. With a combination of these Parameters , I think Port `5985` will show up even when you use `-p-` , or at least , we will get Debug Points !

Comment: It was some troubles with my virtual machine network settings and vpn, now everything works fine. Thank you guys anyway!